# Matlab filtfilt() function implementation in Java

Tags: java, c++, matlab, signal-processing

Has anyone tried implementing matlab's `filtfilt()` function in Java *(or at least in C++)*? If you guys have an algorithm, that would be of great help.

Comment: do one convolution _left to right_, then redo it _right to left_ on the result, that's your `filtfilt`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675053/matlabs-filtfilt-algorithm/27270420#27270420) is my implementation in C++ of the `filtfilt` algorithm as implemented in MATLAB. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 7):

Allright, I know this question is ancient, but maybe I can be of help to someone else who winds up here wondering what `filtfilt` actually does.

Although it is obvious from the docs that `filtfilt` does forward-backward (a.k.a. zero-phase) filtering, it was not so obvious to me how it deals with things like *padding* and *initial conditions*.

As I couldn't find any other answers here (nor elsewhere) with sufficient information about these *implementation details* of `filtfilt`, I implemented a simplified version of `Python`'s `scipy.signal.filtfilt`, based on its source and documentation (so, not `Java`, nor `C++`, but `Python`). I believe the `scipy` version [works the same](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/11466) way as `Matlab`'s.

To keep things simple, the code below was written specifically for a second order [IIR filter](https://community.plm.automation.siemens.com/t5/Testing-Knowledge-Base/Introduction-to-Filters-FIR-versus-IIR/ta-p/520959), and it assumes the coefficient vectors `a` and `b` are known (e.g. obtained from `scipy.signal.butter`, or [calculated by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52764064)).

It matches the `filtfilt` default behavior, using `odd` padding of length `3 * max(len(a), len(b))`, which is applied before the forward pass. The initial state is found using the approach from `scipy.signal.lfilter_zi` ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter_zi.html)).

*Disclaimer*: This code is only intended to provide some insight into certain implementation details of `filtfilt`, so the goal is clarity instead of computational efficiency/performance. The `scipy.signal.filtfilt` implementation is much faster (e.g. 100x faster according to a quick & dirty `timeit` test on my system).

```
import numpy


def custom_filter(b, a, x):
    """ 
    Filter implemented using state-space representation.

    Assume a filter with second order difference equation (assuming a[0]=1):

        y[n] = b[0]*x[n] + b[1]*x[n-1] + b[2]*x[n-2] + ...
                         - a[1]*y[n-1] - a[2]*y[n-2]

    """
    # State space representation (transposed direct form II)
    A = numpy.array([[-a[1], 1], [-a[2], 0]])
    B = numpy.array([b[1] - b[0] * a[1], b[2] - b[0] * a[2]])
    C = numpy.array([1.0, 0.0])
    D = b[0]

    # Determine initial state (solve zi = A*zi + B, see scipy.signal.lfilter_zi)
    zi = numpy.linalg.solve(numpy.eye(2) - A, B)

    # Scale the initial state vector zi by the first input value
    z = zi * x[0]

    # Apply filter
    y = numpy.zeros(numpy.shape(x))
    for n in range(len(x)):
        # Determine n-th output value (note this simplifies to y[n] = z[0] + b[0]*x[n])
        y[n] = numpy.dot(C, z) + D * x[n]
        # Determine next state (i.e. z[n+1])
        z = numpy.dot(A, z) + B * x[n]
    return y

def custom_filtfilt(b, a, x):
    # Apply 'odd' padding to input signal
    padding_length = 3 * max(len(a), len(b))  # the scipy.signal.filtfilt default
    x_forward = numpy.concatenate((
        [2 * x[0] - xi for xi in x[padding_length:0:-1]],
        x,
        [2 * x[-1] - xi for xi in x[-2:-padding_length-2:-1]]))

    # Filter forward
    y_forward = custom_filter(b, a, x_forward)

    # Filter backward
    x_backward = y_forward[::-1]  # reverse
    y_backward = custom_filter(b, a, x_backward)

    # Remove padding and reverse
    return y_backward[-padding_length-1:padding_length-1:-1]
```

Note that this implementation does *not* require `scipy`. Moreover, it can easily be adapted to work in pure python, without even `numpy`, by writing out the solution for `zi` and using lists instead of numpy arrays. This even comes with a substantial performance benefit, because accessing individual numpy array elements in a python loop is much slower than accessing list elements.

The filter itself is implemented here in a simple `Python` loop. It uses the state space representation, because this is used anyway to determine the initial conditions (see `scipy.signal.lfilter_zi`). I believe that the actual `scipy` implementation of the linear filter (i.e. `scipy.signal.sigtools._linear_filter`) does something similar in `C`, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/lfilter.c.src) (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42322743)).

Here's some code providing a (very basic) check for equality of the `scipy` output and `custom` output:

```
import numpy
import numpy.testing
import scipy.signal
from matplotlib import pyplot
from . import custom_filtfilt

def sinusoid(sampling_frequency_Hz=50.0, signal_frequency_Hz=1.0, periods=1.0,
             amplitude=1.0, offset=0.0, phase_deg=0.0, noise_std=0.1):
    """
    Create a noisy test signal sampled from a sinusoid (time series)

    """
    signal_frequency_rad_per_s = signal_frequency_Hz * 2 * numpy.pi
    phase_rad = numpy.radians(phase_deg)
    duration_s = periods / signal_frequency_Hz
    number_of_samples = int(duration_s * sampling_frequency_Hz)
    time_s = (numpy.array(range(number_of_samples), float) /
              sampling_frequency_Hz)
    angle_rad = signal_frequency_rad_per_s * time_s
    signal = offset + amplitude * numpy.sin(angle_rad - phase_rad)
    noise = numpy.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=noise_std, size=signal.shape)
    return signal + noise


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Design filter
    sampling_freq_hz = 50.0
    cutoff_freq_hz = 2.5
    order = 2
    normalized_frequency = cutoff_freq_hz * 2 / sampling_freq_hz
    b, a = scipy.signal.butter(order, normalized_frequency, btype='lowpass')

    # Create test signal
    signal = sinusoid(sampling_frequency_Hz=sampling_freq_hz,
                      signal_frequency_Hz=1.5, periods=3, amplitude=2.0,
                      offset=2.0, phase_deg=25)

    # Apply zero-phase filters
    filtered_custom = custom_filtfilt(b, a, signal)
    filtered_scipy = scipy.signal.filtfilt(b, a, signal)

    # Verify near-equality
    numpy.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(filtered_custom, filtered_scipy,
                                            decimal=12)

    # Plot result
    pyplot.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    pyplot.plot(signal)
    pyplot.plot(filtered_scipy)
    pyplot.plot(filtered_custom, '.')
    pyplot.title('raw vs filtered signals')
    pyplot.legend(['raw', 'scipy filtfilt', 'custom filtfilt'])
    pyplot.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    pyplot.plot(filtered_scipy-filtered_custom)
    pyplot.title('difference (scipy vs custom)')
    pyplot.show()
```

This basic comparison yields a figure like below, suggesting equality to at least 14 decimals, for this specific case (machine precision, I guess?):

[image: filtfilt scipy vs custom implementation]