# Scipy - signaltools.lfilter() function implementation

Tags: python, scipy

I'm working on a butterworth-filter in java. Therefore I've been looking in scipys implementation.

Designing the filter went pretty well, but now I'm stuck. I'm trying to implement a filtfilt() function which uses the lfilter() from the title. This method returns

```
sigtools._linear_filter(b, a, x, axis)
```

So now to my actual question:

Is there any way to have an insight in this _linear_filter() function or can anyone tell me where to find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's here:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/lfilter.c.src

```
scipy_signal_sigtools_linear_filter(PyObject * NPY_UNUSED(dummy), PyObject * args)
```