# vDSP Biquad Remove Transient Signals Swift

Tags: swift, signal-processing, accelerate

I am using Apple's Accelerate Framework, vDSP biquad function https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450838-vdsp_biquad?language=objc#parameters in order to emulate pythons **sosfilt** function. I have done all the filtering but notice I have transient signals that I am trying to remove. In python, this is done with finding the initial conditions from **sosfilt_zi** https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.sosfilt_zi.html#scipy.signal.sosfilt_zi and multiplying by the first element in the data that is being filtered. I followed this amazing example [Matlab filtfilt() function implementation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220671/matlab-filtfilt-function-implementation-in-java/52742099#52742099).

When I print out the initial conditions in python using **sosfilt_zi**, I am getting two values for each section (I'm using a second-order cascade) so I have four values in total.

However in the single channel **biquad** function for iOS, they are asking for **(2*M)+2** for the Delay. I was assuming that the initial conditions are related to the Delay and that this is what I would need to change in order to adjust my signal and remove the transient.

The function definition for the Delay Parameter for the biquad function in iOS is " An array of single-precision values initialized with direct-form 1 “past” state data for each section of the biquad. The length of the array should be (2 * M) + 2, where M is the number of sections. For each section m, Delay[2*m:2*m+1] represent the two delayed input values for section m and Delay[2*M:2*M+1] represent the two delayed output values of the filter. After this function executes, this array contains the final state data of the filters."

If I have 2 sections, then my delay array should look like :

[0:1] - input delay value for section 0

[2:3] - input delay value for section 1

[4:5] - output delay value

I initially had the Delay set to an array of 6 zeros. If the output of **sosfilt_zi** would be the proper values for the two input sections of the Delay, then how could I find the delayed output values of the filter?

Is anyone familiar with vDSP and able to remove transient signals or can explain how to adjust the Delay values for a cascaded second-order sections? Is adjusting the Delay values the correct move and how could I get these values in python?

I was thinking that my delay array would look like (using values shown in second link below):

[0.72095219 -0.28358224] - section 0

[-0.80004591  0.80004591] - section 1

However, I don't know what that output would be if this is even correct. I'd appreciate any help! I've found really little documentation or examples on the iOS biquad function. Thank you!

[Butterworth Bandpass filter - Initial Conditions is being applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2EBp.png)

[Output of sosfilt_zi - gives inital conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQz0B.png)

[Result of Biquad Filter from iOS vDSP on top and result of sosfilt with initial conditions on bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLIXH.png)

[Delays being initialized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6L5g.png)

[Biquad Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoMxL.png)